# Nest Classes using Abstract class? (As well as protect/hide a class)?

Tags: c#

When I was working on nest classes and ran into issues.  That's when somebody told me I need to use interface.  Along the way on implementing the interface, there I learned that interface doesn't allow constructor or passing of the argument parameters.  So, I'm thinking of abstract but I'm uncertain on implementing them and keeping it simple.

In the source code below.  Environment Setting is populated in Console project and is passed on to the Database class in DLL project.

Question #1 - Is it possible to abstract Environment Setting for simplier script?

Question #2 - Using the nested class or not, How do I protected the DealerRepository class (Make it invisible to Console project?  (I'm guessing abstract).

Question #3 - Does DealerRepository class need to be abstracted or what?

What I want here is to protect/hide the DealerRepository class from Console project and not having to pass on EnvironmentSetting class/model repeatly through nest classes.

Thanks...

```
 //EnvironmentSetting.cs
 namespace zTestcase1.Model {
   public class EnvironmentSetting : IDisposable
   {
     public EnvironmentSetting() { } //Constructor...
     public void Dispose() { } /Dispose...

     //Member variables...
     private string _emulation = ""; 
     private string _application = "";
     private string _database = "";

     //Get/Set properties...
     public string Emulation { get {return _emulation;} set {_emulation = value;} }
     public string Application { get {return _application;} set {_application = value;} }
     public string Database { get {return _database;} set {_database = value;} }
  }
}

//DealerRepository.cs
namespace zTestcase1.Data.Dealer
{
  public class DealerRepository : IDisposable
  {
    public DealerRepository(EnvironmentSetting parmEnvironmentSetting) {
       _environmentSettingA = parmEnvironmentSetting; 
    } //Constructor...
    public void Dispose() { }  //Dispose...

    //Member variables...
    private EnvironmentSetting _environmentSettingA = "";

    //Get/Set properties...
    //N/A...

    //Functions...
    public string EnvironmentResponse()
    {
        return "Emulation - " + _environmentSettingA.Emulation + ", Application - " + _environmentSettingA.Application + ", Database - " + _environmentSettingA.Database + "";
    }
    public string DealerProifle_Lookup(string parmName)
    {
        return "(DealerProfile-Lookup) - " + parmName;
    }
    public string DealerProfile_Save(string parmName)
    {
        return "(DealerProfile-Save) - " + parmName;
    }
  }
}

namespace zTestcase1.Library
{
  /*public class Database : IDisposable
  {
    //Class...
    public class DataDealer : IDisposable
    {
        //Constructor...
        public DataDealer(EnvironmentSetting parmEnvironmentSetting)
        {
            _environmentSettingA = parmEnvironmentSetting;
        }
        //Dispose...
        public void Dispose() { }

        //Member variables...
        private EnvironmentSetting _environmentSettingA = null;
        private DealerRepository _dataDealer = null;

        //Get/Set properties...
        public DealerRepository Dealer { get { if (_dataDealer == null) { _dataDealer = new DealerRepository(_environmentSettingA); } return _dataDealer; } }

        //Functions...
        //N/A...
    }*/

    //Constructor...
    public Database(EnvironmentSetting parmEnvironmentSetting)
    {
        _environmentSettingB = parmEnvironmentSetting;
    }
    public void Dispose() { } //Dispose...

    //Member variables...
    private EnvironmentSetting _environmentSettingB = null;
    //private DataDealer _dataDealerB = null;
    private DealerRepository _dataDealerC = null;

    //Get/Set properties...
    //public DataDealer Dealer { get { if (_dataDealerB == null) { _dataDealerB = new DataDealer(_environmentSettingB); } return _dataDealerB; } }
    public DealerRepository Dealer { get { if (_dataDealerC == null) { _dataDealerC = new DealerRepository(_environmentSettingB); } return _dataDealerC; } }

    //Functions...
    //N/A...
  }
}

namespace zTestcase1.Sample1.Console
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EnvironmentSetting environmentSettting = new EnvironmentSetting();
        environmentSettting.Application = "DOS Console";
        environmentSettting.Database = "Not yet hooked up";
        environmentSettting.Emulation = "Development";

        Database _libraryDatabase = new Database(environmentSettting);
        //var test1 = _libraryDatabase.Dealer.Dealer.DealerProifle_Lookup("Best Dealer Cars Buy");
        var test2 = _libraryDatabase.Dealer.DealerProifle_Lookup("Best Dealer Cars Buy");
        System.Console.WriteLine(_libraryDatabase.Dealer.EnvironmentResponse() + " [=] " + test2);
        System.Console.ReadLine(); //To pause the console...

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1:  Instead of ...

```
 //Member variables...
 private string _emulation = ""; 
 private string _application = "";
 private string _database = "";

 //Get/Set properties...
 public string Emulation { get {return _emulation;} set {_emulation = value;} }
 public string Application { get {return _application;} set {_application = value;} }
 public string Database { get {return _database;} set {_database = value;} }
```

Your properties can be expressed this way instead (it is equivalent, except for the initialization to "", which can be done if needed in a constructor instead):

```
 public string Emulation { get; set; }
 public string Application { get; set; }
 public string Database { get; set; }
```

Answer 2/3:  Abstractness and inner classes are not used to limit the visibility of classes to outside callers.  Use `internal` instead: this will give other classes within the same library access, while prohibiting access from outside the current library.  Though, in this case, it looks as though you are working with the `DealerRepository` class from the Console application through the `_libraryDatabase.Dealer` property.  I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Thanks for the clarification on Abstractness and inner class.  Yes, I'm trying to use _libraryDatabase.Dealer to show all functions from the DealerRepository class.  Let's me see if it works when I makes it internal.

Comment: #1 - When I tried making this internal "public class DealerRepository" to "internal class DealerRepository", It did not show up in intellisense on Console project which is what I want but I get compiler or red underline syntax error saying the get accessor is inaccessible.  #2 - Instead of that, if I make the constructor internal, I can see the DealerRepository class in the intellisense on Console project.   Is there a way to make DealerRepository class invisible to the intellisen in the Console project?  Thanks...

Comment: @fletchsod: I'm still not clear what your desired end goal is.  You want: (1) the DealerRepository class not to show up in intellisense, yet (2) for that class to continue working from the same scope using _libraryDatabase.Dealer.  You can't both see and not see the same class!

Comment: Yea, not want DealerRepository class to be visible in intellisense and yet want _libraryDatabaseDealer objects to be visible in intellisense.

Comment: Sorry, this just doesn't make sense.  You either want this class to be usable from this scope, or you don't.  You can't have a class not show up in intellisense, yet expect variables of that type to work properly.

Comment: When you create an instanstance of a class, you create a copy of the DealerRepository objects into _libraryDatabase.Dealer class.  That's how it works in programming.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you need [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).
This will require DI-container. E.g., with [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) the code will look like this:

1) assembly "A.dll" (contracts):

```
public interface IEnvironmentSetting
{
    string Emulation { get; }
    string Application { get; }
    string Database { get; }
}

public interface IDealerRepository
{
    string EnvironmentResponse();
    string DealerProifle_Lookup(string parmName);
    string DealerProfile_Save(string parmName)
}

public interface IDatabase
{
    IDealerRepository Dealer { get; }
}
```

2) Assembly "B.dll" (implementations):

```
[Export(typeof(IDatabase))]
public class Database : IDatabase, IDisposable
{
    [Import]
    public IDealerRepository Dealer { get; set; }

    // other code here...
}

[Export(typeof(IDealerRepository))]
public class DealerRepository : IDealerRepository, IDisposable
{
    [Import]
    private IEnvironmentSetting EnvironmentSetting { get; set; }

    // other code here...
}

[Export(typeof(IEnvironmentSetting))]
public class EnvironmentSetting : IEnvironmentSetting, IDisposable
{
    // other code here...
}
```

3) Assembly "C.exe" (console application). You need to refer assembly "A.dll" only from "C.exe":

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var catalog = // configure composable part catalog here, read MEF docs to find best way for you)
    using (var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog))
    {
        var database = container.GetExportedValue<IDatabase>();

        // you're working with IDatabase and IDealerRepository here,
        // there's no direct access to the particular implementation classes 
        database.Dealer.DealerProifle_Lookup("Best Dealer Cars Buy");

        // ...
    }
}
```